# VBA - Open form within loop then wait for OK click

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that checks for new shops in a sheet. If it finds a new shop it should open a form and prompt the user to select a shop category and then click ok. When the the user clicks ok the value from the dropdown should be selected and then form closes and the loop continues.

The form is calles "shopkat"

This is how it works:

```
For i = LBound(distshops) To UBound(distshops)
        If Not IsEmpty(distshops(i)) Then
            curcell = getrows
            curshop = distshops(i)
            findout = checkifinsheet(curshop)
            If findout = False Then

                Cells(curcell + 1, 1) = curshop
                'show form
                shopkat.Show vbModal
                'shop current shop
                shopkat.shop.Caption = curshop

                'Get value from combo
                Cells(curcell + 1, 2) = shopkat.shopkatcombo.value

                'if user click ok then continue


            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Could anyone help. Thanks a lot!

//////////////////////////// Updated ///////////////////////////////
Module1:

```
Public curcell As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
```

Form shopkat:

```
Private Sub shopkatok_Click()
    If Not shopkat.shopkatcombo.value = "" Then
        ws.Cells(curcell + 1, 2) = shopkat.shopkatcombo.value
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Loop Sheet(Shopcategories)

```
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shopcategories")

    For i = LBound(distshops) To UBound(distshops)
        If Not IsEmpty(distshops(i)) Then
            curcell = getrows()
            curshop = distshops(i)
            findout = checkifinsheet(curshop)

            If findout = False Then


                shopkat.shop.Caption = curshop

                'show form
                shopkat.Show
                If Not IsEmpty(Cells(curcell + 1, 2).value) Then
                    ws.Cells(curcell + 1, 1) = curshop
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question. When you open a form in modal, the next line of the code will not execute till the form is unloaded.

Comment: I think I now understand what you want... one moment

Comment: I have update the code. Hope its more understandable

Comment: Please read my 2nd point again. the `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(curcell + 1, 2).value)` has to be in the OK button of the userform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Do this. (**UNTESTED**)

**A**) Insert a module and paste these lines

```
Public curcell As Long
Dim ws as Worksheet
```

**B**) Next in the Userform's `Ok` Button paste this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ws.Cells(curcell + 1, 2) = shopkat.shopkatcombo.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

**C**) And lastly amend your above code to this

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Rest of code
    '

    '~~> Change this as a applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = LBound(distshops) To UBound(distshops)
        If Not IsEmpty(distshops(i)) Then
            curcell = getrows
            curshop = distshops(i)
            findout = checkifinsheet(curshop)

            If findout = False Then
                ws.Cells(curcell + 1, 1) = curshop

                shopkat.shop.Caption = curshop

                'show form
                shopkat.Show '<~~ No need to mention vbModal. It is default
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    '
    '~~> Rest of code
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work :-) Do I have to call the module? It gives me an error saying that the object is missing